# Prove that there is no closed form of the inverse of the expression $y = x\cot \frac{\pi }{x}$

Tags: closed-form

Prove that there is no closed form of the inverse of the expression $y = x\cot \frac{\pi }{x}$ where $x \geq 3$. I am currently completely lost.

Comment: Again ??  How many times are you going to ask?

Comment: First, a tip -- yelling at people who are helping you on a voluntary basis is not likely to get you an answer. But there is also another reason that you probably won't get an answer. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really answer, just an explanation of why you're not likely to get a satisfactory answer.

This is just a guess, on my part, but proving that the inverse function can't be expressed in "closed form" (using other elementary functions) is somewhat analogous to the problem of proving that certain anti-derivatives cannot be expressed using elementary functions. This latter problem was studied by Liouville, and he proved that antiderivatives of certain functions (like $x^x$ and $e^{-x^2}$) can not be expressed via elementary functions. The proof uses some pretty sophisticated mathematical tools. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) for a bit more info.

Though the analogy is pretty fuzzy, my guess is that your problem is similarly difficult.

Comment: It's too long for a comment.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'm sorry for getting frustrated, but it was somewhat bothersome how I never got a real answer. This helps a lot.

Comment: No problem. The important lesson here is to realize that, outside of calculus classes, functions that can be written in "closed form" are the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Is there a way to approximate this noncontinuous function? I mean, we could find all of it's points fairly easily, and from there, we might be able to make a Taylor Series or something. Just learned concept, not too familiar with this.

For the future, should this be posted as a different question?

Comment: You can approximate anything :-)  Lack of continuity makes it harder, though. Please ask another question, and indicate what properties you want in the approximation. For example, over what interval does it need to be good, what kinds of approximating functions can we use (if you care), where does the approximation need to be exact (if anywhere), how accurate, etc, etc

Comment: @bubba Is the inverse discontinuous?

Answer (score 3):

The question of which elementary functions have elementary inverses was answered in [Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) 68-90.](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/) The [Elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) according to Liouville and Ritt are those functions which are obtained in a finite number of steps by performing algebraic operations and taking exponentials and
logarithms.

The main theorem of that article is:
"If $F(z)$ and its inverse are both elementary, there exist $n$ functions
$\phi_{1}(z)$, $\phi_{2}(z)$, ..., $\phi_{n}(z)$, where each $\phi(z)$ with an odd index is algebraic, and each $\phi(z)$ with an even index is either $e^{z}$ or $log\ z$, such that $F(z)=\phi_{n}\phi_{n-1}...\phi_{2}\phi_{1}(z)$ each $\phi_{i}(z)$ $(i<n)$ being substituted for $z$ in $\phi_{i+1}(z)$."

Therefore you have to show that your function cannot be reduced to that form.

Each of the elementary standard functions, e.g. the trigonometric functions, can be represented as composition of algebraic functions and/or $exp$ and/or $\ln$.

$$x\cot(\frac{\pi}{x})=x\frac{\left(e^{\frac{\pi i}{x}}+e^{-\frac{\pi i}{x}}\right)i}{e^{\frac{\pi i}{x}}-e^{-\frac{\pi i}{x}}}$$

The function of $x$ at the right-hand side is an algebraic function of $x$ and $e^{\frac{\pi i}{x}}$, and $x$ and $e^{\frac{\pi i}{x}}$ are algebraically independent of each other. Further investigation shows, this function cannot be represented in the form of Ritt's theorem. Therefore, Ritt's theorem gives the answer that the inverse function $\phi$ of this function, if $\phi$ exists, cannot be an elementary function.

Comment: Now THIS answers the question.